# Convert a Jekyll Liquid variable (string) to _data file path

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I'm constructing a Jekyll site on Github pages. I have a Github action that delivers fresh daily data to my _data/ file, with today's timestamp:

```
_data/
   somedata_YYYYMMDD.json
```

I can construct a variable in a few ways to capture the filename for today's data file:

```
{% assign today_data = 'now' | date: "%Y%m%d" | prepend: 'site.data.somedata_' %}
```

or

```
{% capture today_data %}
site.data.somedata_{{ 'now' | date: "%Y%m%d" }}
{% endcapture %}
```

In both of these cases, if I try to put the today_data variable to use, Liquid interprets it as an inert string, rather than as [a pointer to a liquid object](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). So, if I try `{{today_data}}`, I get the string "site.data.somedata_20200902", but I'd like it to return the contents of the json file.

I consulted a few other questions, but they don't seem to apply correctly to this situation:

- [using Liquid variables inside of a liquid tag call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call) - This person uses a variable as a string in a tag. I need the variable to be interpreted as a path to a data object.
- [Using filters in Liquid tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972126/using-filters-in-liquid-tags/20521867#20521867) - This person also creates a variable to be used as a string in a tag.
- [Use js variable with Shopify liquid tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634635/use-js-variable-with-shopify-liquid-tag) - Same, I think: using a variable as a string in a tag.
- [Use Liquid filter with Liquid Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647794/use-liquid-filter-with-liquid-tag) - This person is filtering the output of a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, that is a string in both those cases. So it's effectively:

```
{{ 'site.data.somedata_YYYYMMDD' }}
```

Instead, you could do this to get access to and print the object:

```
{% assign today_path = 'now' | date: "%Y%m%d" | prepend: 'somedata_' %}
{{ site.data[today_path] | jsonify }}
```

This way you are accessing the `site.data` object, and dynamically constructing the key/path.